# Adding custom fonts react native ios goes wrong everytime 'react-native link' command is run

Tags: react-native-ios

I've followed everything that is needed to add custom fonts in ios (react native) but failed miserably and stuck in a ping pong situation.

1. Added fonts folder in assets and configure package.json as follows:
   "rnpm": {
   "assets": [
   "./assets/fonts/"
   ]
   }
2. After running 'react-native link' command, Info.plist is updated with the existing 'vector-icons fonts'.

This throws a long thread of error like this...

1. Target 'ProjectName' has copy command from '/Users/apple/Desktop/Nazish/React Native/Projects/ProjectName/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf' to '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bftjmdemjywsedcwunepexyoyjdt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.app/MaterialIcons.ttf'

To get rid of this, I removed the vector-icons font from 'Resources' folder and left the custom ones.

but whenever I run 'react-nativ link' for other installations, the vector-icons again appears in the info.plist and this goes on and on.